# GCP Load balancer Frontend configuration not showing first load balancer in dropdown

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

I created a load balancer with https support with a bucket as a backend service to  host a static web site .

While configuring a second load balancer in order to redirect the http request to https I expected to see the first load balancer ip in the front-end configuration dropdown but no other ips are listed in addition to the ephemeral (Efímera)  .

Is there something I need to enable or expose in order to see previously created load balancers ip´s in the dropdown ?

[image]

Comment: Have you already reserved the public ip of the other load balancer? Otherwise it is expected the ip is not shown there

Comment: You mean reserve it as a static ip ?

Comment: I do not have an answer to this question jet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS, yes you need to reserve a static IP address. HTTP to HTTPS redirect enabled only when a reserved IP address is selected.  To know how to reserve the IP address, follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address).

The Enable HTTP to HTTPS redirect checkbox is only available while creating a new HTTPS Load Balancer. It is not available when editing an existing Load Balancer. For more details on how to enable [http to https redirect](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect).